# Handling special characters in data in Azure Data Factory Copy Activity while writing data into a CSV file

Tags: azure-data-factory

Problem Summary: Records are breaking into multiple lines after ingestion into CSV due to special characters present in data.

I am trying to ingest data from a SQL Database to ADLS using a copy activity in ADF.
The data contains special characters like < ",$,/n,/r,\ >

The resultant CSV file has few records broken into multiple lines.
I have tried changing the column delimiter and the row delimiter in the sink dataset, but nothing helped.

[image: Dataset Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I tried with following data from SQL.

[image]

I didn't changed anything in the dataset configurations and these are the configurations.

[image]

I got the data with mutliple columns when I preview in the storage account.

[image]

This is because of the `,` as Column delimiter. While copying the data, you can change it to other if you want.

But while previewing the same dataset with above configurations from ADF after copy, we can see it showed the correct values.

[image]

So, when you are using the result data in future in ADF or any other, give the same configurations as above for it to get the same data.